# Can you programme the selected page template to display block patterns automatically?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, block-editor, page-template

Ideally, if I select a template called "3 columns", the block patterns layout I've premade would automatically load into place.

I understand you can predetermine regular posts block pattern layouts, and you can also do this with custom post types, but how about page templates?

Comment: do you mean a PHP page template, or one created using a block template file in the database? I suspect you meant the first one as the question doesn't make sense if you meant the latter one ( as you could put a pattern block in the block template HTML file )

Comment: I want to put a pattern block in the template HTML file.  So when the template is selected, the pattern block displays. How do I go about this? Maybe I can't find how to online because I'm using the wrong wording? Thank you

Comment: I want to put a pattern block in the template HTML file. So when the template is selected, the pattern block displays. How do I go about this? Maybe I can't find how to online because I'm using the wrong wording? Thank you @tom-j-nowell

Comment: can you be more specific about what you meant by page templates? You never answered my question. do you mean a PHP page template, or one created using a block template file in the database or a HTML file in the theme? This is important, as some people mention page templates but they actually meant Elementor templates or something else